# How to bring the CXCallController to the front

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating a VOIP App. Most of the logic is similar to the CallKit iOS Swift Tutorial for VoIP Apps (Super Easy) Tutorial.
https://websitebeaver.com/callkit-swift-tutorial-super-easy

My issue is that after running the viewDidLoad(), the CXCallController is not on top of the App, but next to it in the "task manager":

The document that I was following is saying "If you press the lock button on your phone, you'll see that the outgoing call is trying to connect."

How do I bring the CXCallController to the front after the user has accepted the call?

```
import UIKit
import CallKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CXProviderDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let provider = CXProvider(configuration: CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "My App"))
    provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    let controller = CXCallController()
    let transaction = CXTransaction(action: CXStartCallAction(call: UUID(), handle: CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Pete Za")))
    controller.request(transaction, completion: { error in })
}

    func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bring the system call screen to front for the accepted calls. You must provide the UI yourself. System call screen is presented if the phone is locked and you receive a VoIP call OR, if you have 1 VoIP and 1 regular call and you switch between the two.